# why is the if statement ignored python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am comparing filenames in a directory with a list of filenames I generated from an excel specific sheet then moving the files with matching filenames to a new folder called 'moved_files'.Why is my if statement ignored and no files are moved when the code runs and prints "done" at the end?

I have used print statements before the last if statement to see the pdb_filename and filename_gen and some of the filename_gen do match with pdb_filename. The print statement doesn't print although there are files with .pdb at the end in the directory.

Here is the code

```
for filename_gen in list_filename_gen:
    for pdb_filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if pdb_filename.endswith(".pdb"):
            print(pdb_filename)
            if print filename_gen ==print pdb_filename :
                shutil.move(os.path.join(directory, pdb_filename),'/Users/fififoufa/Desktop/files_moved/%s' % (pdb_filename))
print("done")
```

I expect to see files moved when the names exactly match e.g files\xTMEM16A_dimer_OPM_PI4P\500_4.pdb and files\xTMEM16A_dimer_OPM_PI4P\500_4.pdb

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: First of all, `print` returns `None`, so your comparison of two `print` calls will always return `True`.  Nowhere have you compared the file names.  If you suspect that a particular `if` is ignored, where is your trace of the values just before they're compared?  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
  This posting has a lot of superfluous code, and hasn't displayed the values critical to the problem.  Please update.

Comment: Maybe `list_clusternumber` is empty because `ws.nrows <= 5` or `ws.ncols == 0`. This would mean that `list_filename_gen` is also empty. Another possibility is that `directory` does not contain any files.

Comment: `if print(filename_gen)==print(pdb_filename):` Not exactly sure what this line is meant to be doing, but it's going to compare the two print functions, not the values they're printing. This will always become if `None == None:` which evaluates as `True`. If you were trying to see if the two names are equal, try `if filename_gen == pdb_filename:` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're not exactly comparing the two file names, you're instead comparing two print calls which would return True.
            if filename_gen == pdb_filename: